# Preventing repeat answers Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I've build an quiz app so I can practice myself with different question. I want to make sure that once I provides an answer for a particular question, the question get disable to prevent multiple answers being entered, as well I know it's in the Toast section but i'm looking to add a final score at the end in percentage. I would greatly appreciate some help.

```
package com.example.randomuser.androidquiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mTrueButton;
private Button mFalseButton;
private ImageButton mNextButton;
private ImageButton mPreviousButton;
private TextView mQuestionTextView;
private int mCurrentIndex = 0;
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";


private Question[] mQuestionBank = new Question[] {
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionone, false),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questiontwo, true),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionthree, true),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionfour, false),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionfive, true),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionsix, false),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionseven, true),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questioneight, false),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionnine, false),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionten, true),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questionelevn, false),
        new Question(R.string.quiz_questiontwelve, false),
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
       mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
    }

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_textview);
    updateQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1)% mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {
           mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mPreviousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            if(mCurrentIndex < 0){
                mCurrentIndex = 0;
            }
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.falseButton);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });
    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trueButton);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            checkAnswer(true);
     }
    });

}

private void updateQuestion() {
    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userGuess)
{
    boolean a = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isAnswer();
    int messageId = 0;
    if(userGuess == a)
    {
        messageId = R.string.right_answer;
    }
    else{
        messageId = R.string.wrong_answer;
    }

    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 300);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
}

}
```

Comment: Please ask one question in one question. Also it's really unclear what you are actually trying to achieve to be honest. You want to make sure every question is only shown once? Make a list with questions that are unanswered and remove a question that has been asked from this list. Or give it a flag `hasBeenAsked`. There are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Save their responses in a list/array, and use that to dictate the next index.

Comment: You might want to have a look here: https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/challenge-preventing-repeat-answers-how-to-best-save-which-question-has-been-answered/11476 There was exactly the same challenge in Android Big Nerd Ranch Guide to solve. As your question might be considered as a bit too broad here at SO, you might want to look there for some tips.